# ASynchronous Creation of Temp Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asynchronous

I'm currently trying to determine possible issues with creating temporary tables from a web application and how SQL Server naturally determines separate sessions.

```
SELECT blabla, lala FROM table INTO #TempTable
SELECT blabla FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

In the above, while one user of a web application is waiting for the second line to execute, and another user fires off the same 3 lines, what would determine whether the 2nd user gets a "Object already exists" or else a new #TempTable is created for that user.

If each user was on a separate computer on the same network, would SQL server treat this as separate sessions and thus create separate temporary tables.

What about if it is run on the same computer on two different networks?

Comment: Temporary tables are created and stored inside the database until they are dropped, why are you bothering to create a temp table when you could just do the select from the database table with specific parameters passed by the user?

Comment: In the actual web app, I have to return a huge array of COUNTs that each require a separate query that all have similar joins with a few different WHERE statements. I create a temp table with all the joins and stuff and do the WHERE checks off the temp table to avoid doing the joins 100+ times over

Comment: However, I tried with my web app to leave the table open and then run the query in a different browser and the counts didnt return. I'm trying to figure out what SQL Server uses to determine separate sessions (Whether that be IP Addrss, MAC Address, etc)

Comment: @mewi Your last comment should have mentioned an error - local temp tables cannot be accessed outside of the session in which it was created. If an error did not occur, then you must be using **global temp tables** - the difference is very significant.

Comment: I was getting an "Object already exists" error

Comment: Please paste your source code. Common mistake is that each of the commands above are executed on separate connection due to incorrect use of connection pooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user connection to the database is it own session.  These sessions are unique even if you're using connection pooling within SQL Server.  Behind the scenes, SQL Server appends each #tempTable with a single session reference number, so they technically aren't even named the same thing during execution.

If the root of your problem is an error message about the object already existing when you are debugging. Try adding the code snippet below before you create the temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[tempdb]..[#tempTable]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tempTable
END
```

Comment: Is it possible for someone to access the web application from a different computer on the same network and be part of the same user connection as someone else on the network?

Comment: Nope, even being on the exact same computer with the web application opened in a different browser would create a new unique session with its own set of temp tables.  Also, try my code snippet I added after seeing you mention the "Object Already Exists" error.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not determine separate sessions.
It is a client application who create sessions. You can write an application where all traffic to the database use single connection (not so easy) or a separate connection is created for each page (common mistake). Both of the solutions are pretty bad.
In proper design you should use connection pooling and your code should reserve connections from the connection pool as needed.
Even if you are using connection pooling, it is possible that each command is executed on a different connection from the pool.